# Why and how white noise cancels other background noises?

Tags: acoustics, biology, noise, perception

This idea of white noise cancelling other background noises is quite popular these days and I always wonder how it works?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nMfPqeZjc2c

This is a sample of white noise. If I put it on in a noisy place, then I am able to cancel other background noises and sleep well, but without it, it becomes difficult to sleep in a noisy place.

The question is, what is so special about white noise (and other such noises) that it cancels out other background noises and one feels relaxed?

Comment: This question is more about the human auditory system than about physics. White noise simply superposes with other sounds, like all sound waves do (at least until nonlinear effects occur at extremely high volume).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Introduction

First of all, let me state that the clip you provided does not contain *white noise*, but some kind of filtered noise. I haven’t analysed it to conclude on the “colour” of the noise but it is definitely **not** white.

### Clarifying the problem

Now, let me clarify a bit what the “problem” is here. White noise rarely (if ever) cancels out other noise. White noise is more often than not (*always* would be a very good approximation to the frequency this statement is true) incoherent to other noise. The summation of two such sources (incoherent) results in the summation of their energies. Since the energy of travelling waves cannot be negative, when two sources such as the noise clip you provide and any other background noise add up, the total energy will only rise. This is definitely not *cancellation* of the background noise. There are means to cancel noise with “noise”, and is used in active control of noise in headphones for example (or cars and planes nowadays) but it has its limitations and is not a trivial task.

So, if not cancellation, what? If the playback of the noise clip seems to be suppressing the already present background noise, then what is actually happening?

### Masking effect

As has already been commented, this has to do with the *perception* of sound, which is **subjective**. The field of acoustics dealing with the perception of sound is *psychoacoustics* and the relevant phenomenon/effect here is **frequency masking**. A sound can *mask* another sound if their frequencies and amplitudes have specific relations. I will not go into detail on the masking effect but you can find more information [Wikipedia auditory masking page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auditory_masking) and [Wikipedia sound masking page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_masking).

So, what really happens is that you add some noise which masks the offending background noise, not cancelling it but making it imperceivable. Low frequencies can mask higher frequencies more efficiently than high frequencies can mask the low ones. This is most probably one of the reasons that the clip you provided has much energy in the low frequencies, which resembles more *pink noise* than *white noise*.